# Show "fixed font" button regardless if the message is single line or multi line

Tags: feature-request, chat

Literally everyone that is new to the chat is confused how to format a message in order for it to be shown as fixed font. The result is unformatted (and unindented too because the initial spaces are removed) code posted to the chatroom. It doesn't help that *there is no visible interface* for making the code fixed font. Not until the user presses Shift+Enter, which also not obvious. I'd say the first step would be making "fixed font" button visible all the time.

There is *literally* no reason to hide the fixed font button when there is only single line because indenting with 4 spaces also works on single-line messages too.

Comment: This post literally needs a few more "literally"s

Comment: Well, it takes the same space as the Upload button... but that then disappears as soon as you type text.

Comment: What is wrong with reading the [help](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) or the [FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq)? Both of which are linked at the bottom right of every chat window.

Comment: @DavidPostill nobody reads those... and they're not an excuse for an unintuitive UI.

Comment: @canon Clearly wrong as I've read them and I'm not nobody :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Telling people to RTFM never works.

Comment: @milleniumbug Only if they are unteachable.